# Datapath in haml

Tags: svg, haml

I am using HAML with SVG to animate some vector shapes. But when I compile I keep getting an error pertaining to the "data path". I am using the proper syntax ( `{:data-path => "xxx"}` )

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`:data-path` is invalid, it will be parsed as `:data - path` – i.e. the `-` is parsed as a minus, not as part of the symbol.

There are a couple of solutions. The obvious one is to use a string rather than a symbol:

```ruby
"data-path" => "xxx"
```

In Haml you could also use [something like this](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html5_custom_data_attributes):

```haml
%tagname{:data => {:path => "xxx"} }
```

This is more useful when you have several `data-` attributes.